# Viewing application in simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, simulator

I need to show my app to customer but without sending sources codes to him. 
He does not own any iDevice at the moment, but only a Xcode installed on his host with iPhone simulator.

So my question is there a "normal/official" way I can pass him the application binary so he can test it on his simulator ? Probably using xcode archiving ?

PLEASE NOTE : I know what is ad-hoc distribution, please do not suggest this, he does not own a device.

Comment: You can hide some portion of the code, by making Static Library, this way they will be able to run app from xcode to view on simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. You cannot give him the ipa to launch it in simulator. Only the source code. (If he is smart enough to launch it, I think you guess how confused will the client be when you try to explain him stuff around the provisioning profiles and certificates and keys to pair them) ....

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem - however, if this is just about a small tour through the app and not a long time testing, might I suggest another way around this:

Why not using a screensharing app like TeamViewer, which has a version that works without installation and is quite hassle free. And then let him play with the App running on your computer?

Sorry for not having an answer on the question, but that would be an alternative route to take.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution:

Set up a contract with penalty fee if he copy's the code or distributes the code that'll settle you for life.

If he doens't own a device, you could also loan him one with the app installed. Just do an iphone without a sim card or an ipod

Answer (score 0):

Creating an ipa file and run on the simulator is not possible. We can run the simulator using Xcode only. (means by sharing the code). If you are not interested, ask him to buy device.